# Dynamic StatesGroup on aiogram 3.1.1

Tags: python-3.x, django, telegram, aiogram

Good afternoon everyone.

Im working in a company developing telegram bots for businesses, the main stack is Django / Aiogram 3.1.1.

At the moment I am faced with one difficult task and I would like to ask others about the possibility of its implementation.

In short, the task is this:

The database contains a table with questionnaires (field title) and a table associated with the name of the question: the type of question validation (validation of number, name, mailbox, etc.), as well as a table with the user associated with the answer to the questionnaire.

[questionnaires and types DBdiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btLdB.png)

My task is to create a kind of processor for filling out questions from these questionnaires. The difficulty is that, in fact, I could create a StatesGroup and write it like this:

```
class QuestionsStates(StatesGroup):
    email = State()
    phone_number = State()
    full_name = State()
    # . . .
```

Next, I would create handlers for each state, and after receiving and validating the data in the last state, the handlers would send the data to the database and that’s all.

```
@router.message(QuestionsStates.last_state)
async def send_data_to_backend(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_answers = await state.get_data()
    
    # user_answer.get('')
    # send all data with user_id to backend

    # . . .
```

But here comes a problem. Questions in the questionnaire may change, the type of their validation may change, some questions may be deleted, and so on.

Actually what is my question?
Is it possible to implement the creation of dynamic states on aiogram 3.1.1?

I have a couple of ideas, but I'm not sure, maybe there are some other ways.

I will be glad to any advice and any help in this matter.
Thanks in advance and have a nice week!

One of my ideas for implementation was to create a specific function that would work once a minute; it would add new states based on the name of the questionnaire:

```
async def get_anketa_questions():
    questions_response = await django_get_questions()
    for data in questions_response:
        State(state=data.get('name'))
        # idk something like this(i haven't checked if this code will work)
```